# Why is the deleted file commit by default when using the commit command in libgit2?

Tags: libgit2

1. I delete the file: user git_remove_bypath and git_index_write
2. I use the index to commit, and don't commit the file by removed file,but the file by my removed also commit success.

   ```
   int commit(void *repository, const char *file_name[], const unsigned int file, const char *message, void *payload)
   {
       int error = -1;
       git_signature *signature = NULL;
       /*git git;  identify of any object*/
       /*git commit_id; identify of any object*/
       void* index = NULL;
       void* tree = NULL;

       do  /* try catch */
       {
           const char *path = git_repository_path((git_repository*)repository);
            /*get signature*/
           error = git_signature_default(&signature, (git_repository*)repository);
            /*get repository head*/
           error = git_repository_head(&ref_head,(git_repository*)repository);
           if (error == GIT_OK)
           {
               error = git_commit_lookup(&parent_commit, (git_repository*)repository, git_reference_target(ref_head));

           }
           else if (error != -9)
           {
               break;
           }
            /*get repository index*/
           error = git_repository_index((git_index**)&index, (git_repository*)repository);

           for(int i = 0; i < Count; ++i)
           {
                /*get statue*/
               error = git_status_file(&flags, (git_repository *)repository, file_name[i]);
               if(-3 == error || -5 == error)
               {
                   continue;
               }

               if( GIT_STATUS_INDEX_DELETED & flags || GIT_STATUS_WT_DELETED & flags )
               {
                    /*remove file*/
                   error = git_index_remove_bypath((git_index *)index, file_name[i]);  
               }
               else
               {
                    /*add file*/
                   error = git_index_add_bypath((git_index *)index, file_name[i]);
               }
               /*write disk*/
               error = git_index_write((git_index*)index);    

           }

           /* Get the index and write it to a tree */
           error = git_index_write_tree(&git, (git_index*)index);
           /* lookup tree */
           error = git_tree_lookup((git_tree**)&tree, (git_repository *)repository, &git);

           /* Do the commit*/
           error = git_commit_create(&commit_id, (git_repository*)repository, "HEAD", signature, signature, NULL,
   message, (git_tree *)tree, 1, parents);  
       }while(0);

    }
   ```

Comment: There's not nearly enough information in your question.  What does your working directory look like - ie, what's the output of `git status`?  What does your index look like before you create the tree?  What does the tree look like?  What's the output of status _after_ the commit?

Comment: @Edward Thomson.thank you for your answer sincerely,this is my 
Detailed code location：[link] https://github.com/xiaofuhub/BranchTest/blob/serverbranch001/remove&commit.c.  Is it wrong to get tree? how to get the new tree? thanks